# Nginx conf for socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, socket.io

I am using socket.io on my nginx server. 
I followed the doc from nginx to configure my server (http://nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/):

```
  location = / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 501 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  }


upstream frontend {
  server 127.0.0.1:7300;
}
```

However I still get the following error in my browser:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://<MY DOMAIN>/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=oway-6XKt7_HvqfQAAAC'
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Everything works fine locally so I get the problem comes from my nginx.

What should I change to make it work?

Many thanks

Comment: Your upstream is `nautilus-frontend` yet your `proxy_pass` is `http://frontend;`. Typo?

Comment: yes sorry about that, I edited my question

Comment: Hi Spearfisher! Have you solved this problem?
I'm experiencing the same one at my home computer, while my office conputer works perfectly. I would appreciete any hint...